# Flutter pageview make scroll animation continues in circular manner

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to make a carousel in flutter animate in a circular manner. I have **4 items**. I am able to animate to pages I want with `controller.animateToPage(...)` When it reaches the 4th item I try to animate back to the first item (index 0) with `controller.animateToPage(0,)`

**My problem**
The animation works. however, it's not continues. As at now it animates back from 4...all the way to the first item.

I want it to "animate" to the 1 from 4.
I have tried `controllet.jumpTo(0)`  but it doesn't not animate it just pops in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this package [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)
and set `enableInfiniteScroll: true,` for circular animation

```
CarouselSlider(
   items: items,
   options: CarouselOptions(
      height: 400,
      aspectRatio: 16/9,
      viewportFraction: 0.8,
      initialPage: 0,
      enableInfiniteScroll: true,
      reverse: false,
      autoPlay: true,
      autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
      autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
      autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      enlargeCenterPage: true,
      onPageChanged: callbackFunction,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
   )
 )
```